# Proving that equation is true in certain domain

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given equation:
$$\sqrt{4 - x + 4\sqrt{-x}} = 4 - \sqrt{4 - x - 4\sqrt{-x}},$$
how can one prove, that this equation is true only for $x \in [-4, 0]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can set $t:=\sqrt{-x}$ (so that $t\ge0$) and get

$$\sqrt{t^2+4t+4}=4-\sqrt{t^2-4t+4},$$

$$t+2=4-|t-2|,$$

$$t-2=-|t-2|,$$

$$t-2\le0.$$
Hence $$0\le t\le2,$$ $$-4\le x\le0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Put $y = -x \implies \sqrt{4+y+4\sqrt{y}} = 4 - \sqrt{4+y-4\sqrt{y}}\implies 2+\sqrt{y} = 4 - |2-\sqrt{y}|=2+\sqrt{y}$ , and this true for all $y \ge 0$. Thus is true for all $x \le 0$, and $-4 \le x$. The other case which leads to $2+\sqrt{y} = 4 - (\sqrt{y}-2)\implies y = 4\implies x = -4$, and this is part of the solutions covered in the first case.

Comment: After the second $\;\implies\;$ , how did you get that equality? How did you square the right side?

Comment: Still I can't see it...I understand $\;4+y\pm4\sqrt y=(2\pm \sqrt y)^2\;$ , but how do you dispose of the sum on the right hand?

Comment: You repeated $2+\sqrt{y}$ on both sides. $2+\sqrt{y} = 4 - |2-\sqrt{y}|=2+\sqrt{y}$.

Answer (score 1):

squaring the equation
$$\sqrt{4-x+4\sqrt{-x}}+\sqrt{4-x-4\sqrt{-x}}=4$$ we obtain
$$4-x+4\sqrt{-x}+4-x-4\sqrt{-x}+2\sqrt{(4-x)^2-16(-x)}=16$$
simplifying we get
$$8-2x+2\sqrt{(x+4)^2}=16$$
can you proceed?

Comment: It will simplify to the $x + 4$ = $|x + 4|$. For $x \geq -4$ we got terms on both sides canceled, so it means that equation is true $\forall x$ in this interval. However, $x$ has to be lesser than $0$, because so is required by the term $\sqrt{-x}$. Henceforth, solution is interval $[-4, 0]$. I am right? :-)